# clearing a session (logging a user out) in clojure-ring

Tags: session, clojure, ring

With the impression that simply setting the request-map's :session to nil will cause a logout, my code looks like the following:

```
(GET "/logout" [ :as request] 
  (if-let [useremail (get-in request [:session :ph-auth-email])]
    (-> (response {:status 200,
                   :body (pr-str "logged out " useremail),
                   :headers {"Content-Type:" "text/html"}})
        (assoc request [:session nil]))))
```

But I get an error:

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-02-18 09:29:05.134:WARN:oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:/logout

java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized body: {:status 200, :body "\"logged out \" \"sova\"", :headers {"Content-Type:" "text/html"}}
```

Comment: that really depends on how you maintain your session. can you share the code for login?

Comment: Apparently the error message has nothing zo do with the session at all, but with the response in general and the body specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ring.util.response/response`](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html#var-response) expects only the body as parameter since it'll build `:status` and `:headers` around it (see [here](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/1.3.1/ring-core/src/ring/util/response.clj#L41)). A map, however, is not a valid body - only strings, files, streams are allowed.

So, this is what causes the exception; now, on to your question: You can log out a user by setting `:session` to `nil` in your **response** ([source](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj#L73)) - which reduces your code to:

```
(GET "/logout" [:as request] 
  (if-let [useremail (get-in request [:session :ph-auth-email])]
    {:status 200,
     :body (pr-str "logged out " useremail),
     :session nil, ;; !!!
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}}))
```

Comment: aha, response does all that nitty gritty.  makes sense.  thank you, much appreicated

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that "Content-Type" should not have a colon inside, or else it will not set the content type correctly and it'll prompt you to download the file instead of displaying the result to the browser.  Other than that small detail, perfect.

Comment: I adjusted the code example to contain the correct header name.